# Why do I get an error when trying to open the Rebuild Reporting Database page in Sitecore 8.1?

Tags: xdb

I am simply trying to open up the page used for rebuilding the reporting server in `Sitecore 8.1` - `/sitecore/admin/rebuildreportingdb.aspx`.

When I do that I get the following error:

```
>Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.SegmentStorageProvider, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert))
```

From what I can gather that means that either my `Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client` DLL is the wrong version or perhaps the ASPX page itself is not the most up to date version or something. The file version of my DLL is `1.2.1.5488`. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to revert the DLL and the aspx file from Sitecore Website zip package? My theory is that you have got a reference to old DLL somewhere in your project and during rebuild you overwritten it.

Comment: Yes, I tried that.  It didn't help.  Same error.

Comment: Can you specify the exact DLL name you reverted?

Comment: Ok, I think I am getting closer.  I figured out that there were two config files that I had disabled during an upgrade (Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.Services.config and Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Services.config).  Once I re-enabled those I don't get the error message anymore.  However now I get a different error message - Could not find add method: AddCustomProviders (type: Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.SqlReportingStorageProvider)

Comment: Yeah, both of your questions point to the fact that your upgrade did not go correctly. I would suggest that you either do it from scratch against a clean Sitecore 8.1.3 instance, or that you copy all files (binaries, configs, static files) over from the Sitecore package and start from there.

Comment: @CoreyBurnett did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: No.  I even opened a ticket with Sitecore support and they can't figure it out either.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever dialogs stop working after Sitecore Upgrades, there are two things you should check:

1. Did you clear your browser cache (& cookies) as requested during the upgrade?
2. Does your deployment process overwrite any files in the `/sitecore` folder?

It is extremely common for an upgrade to go smoothly, but for some upgraded files to not make it back into your preferred deployment method. Go to http://dev.sitecore.net and grab the zipped web root of your target installation version. Compare the files in the zip with your installation folder. Guaranteed you have an incorrect file in `/sitecore` or you're overwriting a new `/bin` file with an older one from your deployment project.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a stab at this...

> Could not resolve type name:
>   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.SegmentStorageProvider,
>   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client (method:
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert))

This is indicating to me that there is a configuration reference trying to point to **Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.SegmentStorageProvider**. ( I can hear it now, *"Gee... Thanks Mr. Obvious!"*)

However, this is the wrong class name, which makes me think this may be a botched upgrade or config transform.

You'll want to take a look at the `Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.StorageProviders.config` and make sure that **primary** and **secondary** Segment Storage Provider types are pointing to **`Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.AggregationSegmentStorageProvider, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client`** (Note: Aggregation in the class name)

It should look something like this in `showconfig.aspx`:

```xml
  <primarySegmentStorageProvider type="Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.AggregationSegmentStorageProvider, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client" singleInstance="true" patch:source="Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.StorageProviders.config">
    <param ref="experienceAnalytics/deployment/services/aggregationSegmentRepository" />
    <param ref="experienceAnalytics/deployment/logger" />
  </primarySegmentStorageProvider>
  <secondarySegmentStorageProvider type="Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.AggregationSegmentStorageProvider, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client" singleInstance="true" patch:source="Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.StorageProviders.config">
    <param ref="experienceAnalytics/deployment/services/secondaryAggregationSegmentRepository" />
    <param ref="experienceAnalytics/deployment/logger" />
  </secondarySegmentStorageProvider>
```

Hope this helps!